# Built in Analyzer in Xcode 3.1.4

Tags: iphone, xcode, llvm, analyzer

I wonder if the built in Analyzer in Xcode 3.1.4 makes it redundant to use LLVM/Clang Static Analyzer separately?

Please refer to the original article here: [Finding memory leaks with the LLVM/Clang Static Analyzer](http://www.fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2008/08/finding-memory-leaks-with-the-llvmclang-static-analyzer/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. (assuming there's a Build and Analyze option in 3.1.4, I thought it only made it to Snow Leopard).

Of course, the builds available directly from LLVM are newer than the ones with Xcode, so they probably fix some issues that may exist with the one currently packaged with Xcode. However, the static analyzer is pretty darn mature already, so you're probably not missing out on much.